# Ошибка в зависимостях после обновления firebase-messaging до версии 22.0.0

Tags: android, firebase

Обновил библиотеку Firebase Messaging с 21.1.0 до 22.0.0 и получаю с десяток одинаковых ошибок:

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zza found in
> modules jetified-firebase-iid-19.0.0-runtime
> (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0) and
> jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime
> (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.

Что случилось и что нужно делать? В release-notes написано так:

> Cloud Messaging version 22.0.0 Removed dependency on the deprecated
> Firebase Instance ID SDK.
>
> Caution: This is a breaking change for apps that use FCM and the
> deprecated Firebase Instance ID API to manage registration tokens. We
> strongly recommend migrating to FCM's token APIs. If you're unable to
> migrate to the replacement APIs, add a direct dependency on the
> firebase-iid library to your build.gradle file.

Но я не знаю ни о каком IID, у меня его нет в проекте. Вот библиотеки firebase, которые есть в проекте:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-datatransport:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:20.0.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx:19.1.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:19.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.2"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:21.0.0'
```

Очень часто по всему stackoverflow (в том числе и англоязычном) я натыкаюсь на подобные вопросы, причем ответы на них всегда по типу "обнови/понизь версию той или иной либы", расскажите, как победить мою ошибку и как ориентироваться в этой файрбейз-каше. Возможно, у меня несовместимости вообще

Comment: ПОпробуйте как сказано в ошибке явно добвить эту либу: `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб очень интересно. я сперва сразу же попробовал прописать зависимость но только версию 22.0.0, вылезала другая ошибка. 21.1.0 помогла, спасибо, но как это работает..

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, раньше эта либа была встроена в либу пущей. Теперь её там нет. Как нет и апдейта. Так что надо добавить последнюю имеющуюся, найдя номер версии на сайте Firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ПОпробуйте как сказано в ошибке явно добвить эту либу:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"
```